# Как в svg circle сделать нулевую заполненность круга

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-variables

У меня есть вот такая вёрстка svg круга

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.progressbar {
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 10px;
  --color: rgb(0, 186, 16);
  --percent: 0;
  /* процент, насколько заполнен круг */
  --PI: 3.141592;
  --r: 30;
  --strokeWidth: 2;
  --lengthCircle: calc( 2 * var(--PI) * var(--r));
}

.progressbar circle {
  r: var(--r);
}

.progressbar text {
  fill: var(--color);
}

.progressbar__track {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ededed;
  stroke-width: var(--strokeWidth);
}

.progressbar__thumb {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: calc( var(--lengthCircle) * var(--percent) / 100) var(--lengthCircle);
  stroke: var(--color);
  stroke-width: var(--strokeWidth);
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.progressbar__percent {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="progressbar" viewBox="0 0 62 80">
  <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="31" cy="31"></circle>
  <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="31" cy="31"></circle>
  <text x="32" y="33" class="progressbar__percent" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
    <tspan>0</tspan>
    %
  </text>
  <text x="32" y="73" class="progressbar__info" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
    <tspan>Загрузочка ...</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Я бы хотел придумать, как можно сделать так, когда CSS переменная `--percent` для `.progressbar` равняется 0, не было видна зелёной точкой на старте, сверху круга.
Я приложу свой вариант в ответах, но может кто-то предложит что-то получше.

**UPD:** я приложил свой вариант, но хотелось бы, чтобы кто-то додумался, как можно было бы это правило описать в CSS.
Вот это правило:

> opacity = 0, если `--percent` === 0
> opacity = 1, если `--percent` !== 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем я всё равно управляю изменением CSS переменной `--percent` из JS, поэтому вот такое я придумал, просто по умолчанию в CSS `opacity: 0` для `.progressbar__thumb`, а при анимации.

```
.to(progressbarThumb, {
  opacity: 1,
  duration: 0.1
})
```

```js
const progressbarThumb = document.querySelector('.progressbar__thumb');
const progressbarPercent = document.querySelector('.progressbar__percent > tspan');
const progressbarText = document.querySelector('.progressbar__info > tspan');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function onUpdateGsap() {
  const percent = gsap.getProperty(progressbarThumb, '--percent');

  if (percent > 99) {
    progressbarText.textContent = 'Закончили?';
  } else if (percent > 60 && percent < 99) {
    progressbarText.textContent = 'Разгоняемся!';
  } else if (percent > 40 && percent < 60) {
    progressbarText.textContent = 'Погнали!';
  } else if (percent > 0 && percent < 40) {
    progressbarText.textContent = 'Загрузочка ...'
  }
  progressbarPercent.textContent = Math.round(percent);
}


const tl = gsap.timeline({
    defaults: {
      duration: 5,
      ease: 'linear'
    }
  })
  .to(progressbarThumb, {
    opacity: 1,
    duration: 0.1
  })
  .to(progressbarThumb, {
    '--percent': 100,
    onUpdate: onUpdateGsap
  });

tl.paused(true);

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (btn.classList.contains('active')) {
    btn.classList.remove('active');
    tl.reverse();
  } else {
    btn.classList.add('active');
    tl.play();
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.progressbar {
  max-width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: block;
  --color: rgb(0, 186, 16);
  --percent: 0;
  /* процент, насколько заполнен круг */
  --PI: 3.141592;
  --r: 30;
  --strokeWidth: 2;
  --total: calc( var(--PI) * var(--r));
}

.progressbar circle {
  r: var(--r);
}

.progressbar text {
  fill: var(--color);
}

.progressbar__percent {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.progressbar__track {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ededed;
  stroke-width: var(--strokeWidth);
}

.progressbar__thumb {
  fill: transparent;
  --strokeDasharray: calc(2 * var(--total) * var(--percent) / 100) calc(2 * var(--total));
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: var(--strokeDasharray);
  stroke: var(--color);
  stroke-width: var(--strokeWidth);
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn {
  --color1: black;
  --color2: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--color2);
  color: var(--color1);
  padding: 5px 8px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid var(--color1);
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-property: border-color, background-color, color;
}

.btn.active {
  --color1: white;
  --color2: black;
  border-color: var(--color2);
}
```

```html
<svg class="progressbar" viewBox="0 0 62 80">
  <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="31" cy="31"></circle>
  <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="31" cy="31"></circle>
  <text x="32" y="33" class="progressbar__percent" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"><tspan>0</tspan>%</text>
  <text x="32" y="73" class="progressbar__info" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"><tspan>Загрузочка ...</tspan></text>
</svg>

<div class="btn">Туда-сюда</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

**UPD:** Получилось то, что я хотел изначально, вариант с установкой прозрачности чисто в CSS:

```js
const progressbarThumb = document.querySelector('.progressbar__thumb');
const progressbarPercent = document.querySelector('.progressbar__percent > tspan');
const progressbarText = document.querySelector('.progressbar__info > tspan');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function onUpdateGsap() {
  const percent = gsap.getProperty(progressbarThumb, '--percent');

  if (percent > 99) {
    progressbarText.textContent = 'Закончили?';
  } else if (percent > 60 && percent < 99) {
    progressbarText.textContent = 'Разгоняемся!';
  } else if (percent > 40 && percent < 60) {
    progressbarText.textContent = 'Погнали!';
  } else if (percent > 0 && percent < 40) {
    progressbarText.textContent = 'Загрузочка ...'
  }
  progressbarPercent.textContent = Math.round(percent);
}


const tl = gsap.timeline({
    defaults: {
      duration: 5,
      ease: 'linear'
    }
  })
  .to(progressbarThumb, {
    '--percent': 100,
    onUpdate: onUpdateGsap
  });

tl.paused(true);

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (btn.classList.contains('active')) {
    btn.classList.remove('active');
    tl.reverse();
  } else {
    btn.classList.add('active');
    tl.play();
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.progressbar {
  max-width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: block;
  --color: rgb(0, 186, 16);
  --percent: 0;
  /* процент, насколько заполнен круг */
  --PI: 3.141592;
  --r: 30;
  --strokeWidth: 2;
  --total: calc( var(--PI) * var(--r));
}

.progressbar circle {
  r: var(--r);
}

.progressbar text {
  fill: var(--color);
}

.progressbar__percent {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.progressbar__track {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ededed;
  stroke-width: var(--strokeWidth);
}

@property --ceil {
  syntax: '<integer>';
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.progressbar__thumb {
  fill: transparent;
  --strokeDasharray: calc(2 * var(--total) * var(--percent) / 100) calc(2 * var(--total));
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: var(--strokeDasharray);
  stroke: var(--color);
  stroke-width: var(--strokeWidth);
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  --percent01: calc(var(--percent) / 100);
  --ceil: calc(var(--percent01) + 0.499);
  --opacity: var(--ceil);
  opacity: var(--opacity);
}

.btn {
  --color1: black;
  --color2: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--color2);
  color: var(--color1);
  padding: 5px 8px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid var(--color1);
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-property: border-color, background-color, color;
}

.btn.active {
  --color1: white;
  --color2: black;
  border-color: var(--color2);
}
```

```html
<svg class="progressbar" viewBox="0 0 62 80">
  <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="31" cy="31"></circle>
  <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="31" cy="31"></circle>
  <text x="32" y="33" class="progressbar__percent" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"><tspan>0</tspan>%</text>
  <text x="32" y="73" class="progressbar__info" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"><tspan>Загрузочка ...</tspan></text>
</svg>

<div class="btn">Туда-сюда</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
```